# Open complete/ regular browser window from pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, browser, popupwindow

In my site I have a pop up window which get opened on page load. This pop up contains a link

`<a href='newpage.html' target='_blank'>click here to go to page</a>`

Currently when user clicks on the link, new page either opens in same pop up window or it opens a new pop up window.

How can I achieve it so instead of new page opens in a pop-up window, it opens in a regular browser window.

Is there any tool and what's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean have the page open as a new tab instead of a popup window, I believe the default behaviour of window.open with the '_blank' attribute should do this. Something like this, in regular JS:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('[target="_blank"]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function (link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var win = window.open('http://www.example.com', '_blank');
    win.focus();
  });
});
```

Or in JQuery:

```
$('[target="_blank"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var win = window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
  win.focus();
});
```

However, it's worth noting that most (if not all) browsers allow users to override that behaviour and force windows to either always open as new tabs or new windows. Just bear that in mind when testing if you're not seeing the expected results. As far as I know, if a user has specified the behaviour, there is no way to override it (and nor should there be, really).